# Save echo statement in session variable

Tags: php, echo, session-variables

Okay, so I can echo out this just fine. (it will echo the name from a post in the database)

```
<?php echo $rows['name']; ?>
```

My question is, how I save this name in a session variable.

I have tried this:

```
<?php $rows['name'] = $_SESSION['name']; ?>
```

But it doesn't work :-(

Comment: Reverse it `$_SESSION['name'] = $rows['name'];`. Also don't forgot to add `session_start();` at top of your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment to a session variable goes the other way around:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $rows['name'];
```

At a later stage you can fetch the value again:

```
echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

Also make sure that you have `session_start()` at the top of scripts that access the session.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning it in a reverse way, you are assigning `$_SESSION['name']` to `$rows['name']`

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $rows['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the other way around :)

```
<?php $_SESSION['name'] = $rows['name']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is vice versa

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $rows['name'];
```